# How to assign § key as shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In the Options/Keyboard VS wont allow assigning § as a shortcut key (the key before number 1 key), alt/shift/ctrl+§ does work, but would prefer without modifier keys..

Is there some reason why this key cannot be assigned,
or are there alternative ways to assign this key as a shortcut? 
(maybe editing it into some settings files?)

Using VS2015 Community Update 1 on win10.

Comment: Reserved on a USA keyboard layout as well, mapped to a back-tick there.  Part of the issue, I think, you cannot re-assign keys that produce text when pressed.  Back-tick is allowed with modifiers, same as what you see, best to assume that they just didn't make a special rule for the Finish layout.  There are utilities around that remap the virtual key, like KeyTweak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, instead of assigning shortcut to "Global"-scope,
use "Text Editor"-scope instead, it then accepts §-key.

There is also Environment Import/Export settings, which saves the config to text file, didnt test if could had manually replaced "ctrl+§" with "§" there..

*using § key as a quick "Go to Definition" shortcut